# Opencv Java fillConvexPoly and approxPolyDP functions

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I have my C++ code of following:

```
// ROI by creating mask for the trapezoid
Mat mask = Mat(frame.rows, frame.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

// Create Polygon from vertices
approxPolyDP(pointsForTrapezoid, roiPolygonized, 1.0, true);

// Fill polygon white
fillConvexPoly(mask, &roiPolygonized[0], roiPolygonized.size(), 255, 8, 0);
```

which I want to convert to Java, since I'll be using OpenCV in Java from now on.

In Java, I tried the following:

```
    // ROI by creating mask for the trapezoid
    Mat mask = new Mat(frame.rows(), frame.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));

    // Create Polygon from vertices
    MatOfPoint2f tmpTrapeziod = new MatOfPoint2f();
    MatOfPoint2f tmpROI = new MatOfPoint2f();
    tmpTrapeziod.fromList(pointsForTrapezoid);
    tmpROI.fromList(roiPolygonized);
    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(tmpTrapeziod, tmpROI, 1.0, true);

    // Fill polygon white
    Imgproc.fillConvexPoly(mask, tmpROI, new Scalar(255), 8, 0);
```

However the last line is giving the error of:

```
The method fillConvexPoly(Mat, MatOfPoint, Scalar, int, int) in the type Imgproc is not applicable for the arguments (Mat, MatOfPoint2f, Scalar, int, int)
```

I am quite confused at the moment about the types `MatOfPoint` and `MatOfPoint2f`, seems it is not as straightforward as in C++.

Did anyone face a similar issue?

Comment: I don't know much Java but the method signature indicates it accepts `MatOfPoint` not `MatOfPoint2f` so it wants int coords not float coords

Comment: if I do that then the other function gives error.

Comment: In C++ version all I do is collecting points in a vector, and then passing this vector to these functions which draw and fill a trapezoid. I want to do the same in Java, and I face tons of problems for some reason.

Comment: You mean `approxPolyDP`? I don't know but the fact remains it's an incompatible type so you need to convert back to int points

Comment: I want these two functions to work without causing problems to each other, like in C++ version which I shared above. If someone could help me converting these functions' parameters to Java ones, I'd be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Imgproc.fillConvexPoly(mask, new MatOfPoint(tmpROI), new Scalar(255), 8, 0);
```

[Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint.html#MatOfPoint-org.opencv.core.Mat-) - so explanatory that I need to emphasize the **Try**